# Can program in supervisor mode execute codes in user mode on RISC-V?

Tags: riscv

For simplify, we talk about RV32 in this topic.

The RISC-V has a `SUM` flag in `sstatus` CSR. Which is described by the specification below:

> The SUM (permit Supervisor User Memory access) bit modifies the privilege with which S-mode loads and stores access virtual memory. When SUM=0, S-mode memory accesses to pages that are accessible by U-mode (U=1 in Figure 4.18) will fault. When SUM=1, these accesses are permitted.

In brief, when SUM=1, codes in S-mode can read data(in `page A`) owned by U-mode. I was wondering that can codes in S-mode jump to and run codes in `page A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not allowed. Here is a paragraph from the spec that mentioned this.

> The SUM (permit Supervisor User Memory access) bit modifies the
> privilege with which S-mode loads and stores access virtual memory.
> When SUM=0, S-mode memory accesses to pages that are accessible by
> U-mode (U=1 in Figure 5.18) will fault. When SUM=1, these accesses are
> permitted. SUM has no effect when page-based virtual memory is not in
> effect, nor when executing in U-mode. Note that S-mode can never
> execute instructions from user pages, regardless of the state of SUM.

**Note that S-mode can never execute instructions from user pages, regardless of the state of SUM.**

And spec further mentions why it's not allowed and how to work around some use cases:

> The SUM mechanism does not avail S-mode software of permission to
> execute instructions in user code pages. Legitimate uses cases for
> execution from user memory in supervisor context are rare in general
> and nonexistent in POSIX environments. However, bugs in supervisors
> that lead to arbitrary code execution are much easier to exploit if
> the supervisor exploit code can be stored in a user buffer at a
> virtual address chosen by an attacker.

> Some non-POSIX single address
> space operating systems do allow certain privileged software to
> partially execute in supervisor mode, while most programs run in user
> mode, all in a shared address space. This use case can be realized by
> mapping the physical code pages at multiple virtual addresses with
> different permissions, possibly with the assistance of the instruction
> page- fault handler to direct supervisor software to use the alternate
> mapping.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! I think I refered to a wrong version of specification and missed the words. I will transfer to a latter specification.